# DropdownList Is not removing previous elements. (JQuery)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have two dropdownlists in my View

First display Companies , second Vacancies related to that specific company.

So when I select company, I see in second selector Vacancies related to it

Here is code in View

```
<div class="right-grid-in-grid" style="width:100%;">
                <div style="margin-left:20px;width:50%; ">
                    @Html.DropDownList("Company", ViewBag.Companies as SelectList, "Компания", new { @class = "greeting" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VacancyId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div style="margin-left:20px;width:100%">
                    <select name="id" id="vacancy" style="width:55%" class="greeting" data-url="@Url.Action("Vacancies","Questions")" >
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Вакансия</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </div>
```

and I fill second selector with AJAX call like this

```
<script>
$(function () {
        $("#Company").change(function (e) {
            var $vacancy = $("#vacancy");
            var url = $vacancy.data("url") + '?companyId=' + $(this).val();
            $.getJSON(url, function (items) {
                $.each(items, function (a, b) {
                    $vacancy.append('<option value="' + b.Value + '">' + b.Text + '</option>');
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

My problem in this: when I select  company first time I see all vacancies related to it. But when I select another company, I will see vacancies from first company and vacancies from second company.

How I can fix this?

Comment: Clear the options first - `$vacancy.empty();` before your `$.each()`

Comment: And suggest you study the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym)

Comment: Thank's it helps@StephenMuecke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed clearing your vacancies dropdown at change event of company. so add `$("#vacancy").empty();` in your Script code.

```
<script>
$(function () {
     $("#Company").change(function (e) {

        $("#vacancy").empty();  
        var $vacancy = $("#vacancy");
        var url = $vacancy.data("url") + '?companyId=' + $(this).val();
        $.getJSON(url, function (items) {
            $.each(items, function (a, b) {
                $vacancy.append('<option value="' + b.Value + '">' + b.Text + '</option>');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank's dude, It helps